# '{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}'::jsonb ?| array['b', 'd'] expression equivalent for integer array

Tags: postgresql, filtering, jsonb

Is there a way to achieve this functionality for integer array?

```
jsonb ?| text[] → boolean
Do any of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?
'{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}'::jsonb ?| array['b', 'd'] → t
```

the description above is from [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE), I would like to achieve same thing to filter json array of integers if it contains any from integer array, something like this:

```
'[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb ?| array[1, 2]
```

but I'm getting an error

```
[42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb ?| integer[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 87
```

Comment: Yes I get that, I'm trying to find out if there is any alternative which lets me do equivalent functionality for `int[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple versions I think this one is the simplest I've got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM "Table" t
JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(t."TypeJson"::jsonb) "Type" ON TRUE
WHERE "Type"::integer in (1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the containment operator:

```
'[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb @> ANY (ARRAY['[1]'::jsonb, '[2]'::jsonb])
```

Comment: yes it does the job, my only concern is its efficiency but for now seems ok. Thanks for help

Comment: actually I was wrong, it only returns if both 1,2 are present in left side of jsonb, I want it to be true even if one of the elements in left side array contains any one of the right side array elements

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer to cover that.